# как установить библиотеку aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

при запуске кода в терминале появляется ошибка ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiogram'
команда pip install aiogram не работает и выдает ошибку

Как мне установить данную библиотеку(aiogram)

Comment: Какую ошибку? .

Comment: Вероятно, у вас установлен python 3.11 или выше, для которых обновление aiogram еще не вышло. Рекомендую снизить питон до десятой версии.

Comment: @Глеб давно вышло уже

Comment: @andreymal O_O Только недавно у меня вылетал. Ну, значит у него 12 или 13 версия...

Comment: @Глеб так для 3.12 и вышло два месяца назад

Comment: @andreymal,  значит, у него 13 версия.